# can the bride's family force Sheva Brachot

Tags: halacha, sheva-brachos

the shuchan aruch says:
[Even HaEzer 64.4](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.64.4)

> אִם הֶחָתָן אֵינוֹ רוֹצֶה לַעֲשׂוֹת סְעֻדָּה, וּקְרוֹבֵי הַכַּלָּה רוֹצִים שֶׁיַּעֲשֶׂה סְעֻדָּה, כּוֹפִין אוֹתוֹ שֶׁיַּעֲשֶׂה סְעֻדָּה לְפִי כְּבוֹדוֹ וּלְפִי כְּבוֹדָהּ
>   If the bridegroom doesn't want to make a feast, but the bride's relatives do want him to make a feast, we compel the bridegroom to make a feast according to his honor and her honor.

is this regarding one meal (if yes then when must it be? (can it be a few days after the wedding?)) or all the Sheva Brachot?
can the bride's family force them (because of the above law) to have Sheva Brachot everyday?

Comment: "to have Sheva Brachot everyday" Only if his honor and her honor deserve that many

Comment: If they're forcing each other to do anything in the first week, that doesn't bode well for the next 100 years.

Comment: @DoubleAA so you are saying that yes (that if in her family and his family they always have all days then the family of the bride can force the groom to make it for 7 days) (is it "his honor **and** her honor"  or  "his honor **or** her honor, the one which is grater"?)

Comment: @Heshy that is only a problem if you live with your inlaws

Comment: @DoubleAA see aruch hashulhan 64.12 here http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14243&st=&pgnum=372