# Is there ever a case that the groom can get back the money he used for the wedding

Tags: halacha, marriage, money

Halachikly the groom is the one who pays for the wedding (last paragraph on this page [Igros Moshe 7 even ezer 4:92:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=921&st=&pgnum=160) and [can the bride's family force Sheva Brachot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/86875/5120) )

Is there ever a case that the bride's side needs to pay him back his expenses for the wedding (or is it just his loss)?

Possible theoretical examples

1. If the bride cheated him, for example if he did not have the ability to check that she is missing a toe, and she did not tell him about it, and when he found out (before they had relations) he did not like it , so the marriage is void or
2. if right after the chuppa she became a a moredes (before they had relations)
   (it seems that maybe if the wife's side payed for the wedding (as explained in the Igros Moshe above), in case of divorce accoring to the Mechaber (תטול בלאותיה הקיימים) he must pay her back all her wedding expences, if he has cash [S"A E"H 77:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Even_HaEzer.77.2))

Sources please

Comment: I do not see any way to defend R' Moshe's conclusion that wedding costs are owed as Nichsei Tzon Barzel. He makes a very strained argument for the groom repaying for the wedding in case of divorce. First, I was taught that the reason the bride pays for the feast is so that he would not be believed if he says she is not a virgin, and that is more reasonable than saying he is believed because he would otherwise have to pay it back, especially as if he is believed and he divorces her because she was not a virgin she would not be entitled to a refund on the wedding.

Comment: R' Moshe also writes that "we do not find anywhere that we no longer believe claims that the bride was not a virgin" but do we find anywhere that we do believe such claims when she has arranged the wedding? Also, we have never seen anywhere, from the Gemara until this Igros Moshe, that wedding expenses must be repaid in case of divorce, which is far more relevant and compelling than his argument about viriginity claims.

Comment: @simyou I do not agree with you, but someone is questioning Rav Moshe, saying that if the husband found a donator to pay for the wedding (sponsoring only the wedding and not letting the husband use the money for other things) , would the husband be believed (regarding virginity)? (Do you have a source regarding that the bride/'s-side pays so the the groom will not be believed?)

Comment: Another problem is that the reasoning for believing his claim is not only that he paid for the wedding, but that he "would not make the effort of making the party and then ruin it for no reason", which would not apply when he has not done any work, and especially if he would have no reason to think that he would be forced to pay for the party at a later date.

Comment: @simyou where does it say that if she paid we do not believe him? https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Even_HaEzer.68

Comment: @simyou Rav Moshe says that he **will** be forced to pay at a later date (death or divorce)

Comment: Taz E"H 68:6 http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=eh_x7702 says he is not believed if her family made the wedding.

Comment: @simyou thank you, so it seems Rav Moshe argues with the Taz

Comment: The Taz actually undermines his argument, since he writes that "we have not found that in modern times he would not be believed", but actually we do find this, in the Taz.

Comment: @simyou that is a scary thought for me

Comment: Your second case is not theoretical... It happened to my friend cousin.

Comment: @Alaychem how did they resolve the money issues

Comment: @hazoriz I never asked him, now maybe I will...